# How to write nuxtJs apollo client mutation with custom input type

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client

I have the following graphql mutation in a file named registerUserGql.graphql

```
mutation addUser($user:AddUserInput) {
  addUser(
    user:$user){
    code
    success
    message
    user{
      firstName
      lastName
      email
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported this .graphql file where I write the client code as below:

```
import registerUserGql from '../gql/registerUser.gql';
```

In apollo client I am writing the mutation call like below:

```
  cosnt user = 
        {
           firstName: "Fozle Rabbi",
           lastName: "Shafi",
           email: "frshafi49@gmail.com",
           password: "123456",
           emergencyContactNo: "12365589955"
        }

  const client = this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
  const response = await client.mutate({
                     mutation: registerUserGql,
                     variables: user
                   });
```

When run the code, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: GraphQL error: user validation failed: emergencyContactNo: Path `emergencyContactNo` is required., password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required., lastName: Path `lastName` is required., firstName: Path `firstName` is required
```

The custom input type in the schema for the user is like below:

```
# input
input AddUserInput {
    firstName:String!
    lastName:String!
    email:String!
    password:String!
    emergencyContactNo:String!
    profileImage:String
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone assists me to figure out the problem.

Comment: `variables: user` is not the same as `variables: { user }`

Comment: @DanielRearden how ? would you please elaborate a little bit ?

Comment: The former sets variables to user, the latter sets variables to an object with a property named `user` whose value is set to `user`

Comment: @DanielRearden if you meant the variables should be like "variables: { user:user }", then you are correct. It solves the problem

Comment: `{ user }` and `{ user: user }` are equivalent